# can't mount ext4 partition on ubuntu mate 16.04

Tags: ext4

Recently I can't mount a 8TB hard drive formatting as ext4 on ubuntu mate 16.04 on odroid. It shows the error: Error mounting drive exit status 32: mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdxx, missing codepage or helper program, or other error. Meanwhile it's mounted normally on ubuntu 21.10. I wonder it is the OS problem or my hard drive problem.

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 is quite old, my guess would be the old kernel doesn't support some of the new ext4 features 21.10 supports. Check the logs (`journalctl -r`) there should be a error message from kernel with more details.

Comment: Is this one large partition? And do you have backup to another large drive? First check smartstatus, either in Disks or Gnome Disks which may need to install In Disks is Smart Data:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/983619/s-m-a-r-t-data-no-longer-available-in-ubuntu-16-04-disks-application or: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools If drive ok then you may need fsck: http://askubuntu.com/questions/642504/ubuntu-14-04-is-not-booting-normaly-after-a-manual-hard-boot/642789#642789 Since so large any file recovery  tool like photorec may take weeks.

Comment: Another possibility is that the device names are different on the two systems, so you are trying to mount the wrong /dev/sdX device.

Comment: @VojtechTrefny You are right, I created the ext4 partition in ubuntu 20.04. Therefore it is not mountable by the odroid. When I upgraded the odoid to ubuntu 18.04 it can read normally.